# Adding an individual file to PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm attempting to use `PyInstaller` with `pyarmor`. I'm using pyarmors "super mode", which creates `pytransform.pyd` at the root of my module.

For the record, I'm not using a spec file, instead I'm doing it python with `PyInstaller.__main__.run(args)`. Not sure if that makes any difference.

Directory structure:

```
c:/dist/
    module/
        *.py  # Obfuscated code
    data/
        stuff.json
    pytransform.pyd
```

I'm already using `--add-data C:/dist/module;module` and `--add-data C:/dist/data;data` to include most of the necessary files, however I'm struggling with `pytransform.pyd`.

If I use `--add-data C:/dist/pytransform.pyd;pytransform.pyd`, I get this error when running the built executable. It looks like it's assuming it's a directory.

```
pytransform.pyd\pytransform.pyd could not be extracted!
fopen: No such file or directory
```

If I use `--add-binary C:/dist/pytransform.pyd;pytransform.pyd`, I get this error when building:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Peter\\AppData\\Roaming\\pyinstaller\\bincache00_py37_64bit\\pytransform.pyd\\pytransform.pyd'
```

I checked the bincache folder, and it actually contains `pytransform.pyd`, so it's halfway there.

How can I add just a single file to the executable?

Answer (score 0):

It worked when adding it as a hidden import, using `--hidden-import=pytransform`.

I would still be interested knowing why the `--add-data` and `--add-binary` didn't work though.